# Wrong result on adding two numbers in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just moved from Python 2.7 to 3 and I have the following strange issue.

**Expected behavior:**

```
a = 0.07
b = 0.08
a+b
>> 0.15
```

**What I get instead:**

```
a = 0.07
b = 0.08
a+b
>> 0.15000000000000002
```

**My Environment:**

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
>> 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Comment: Sorry guys. I was looking for a Python specific question and didn't see that one.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).